Is HTTP keep alive dependent on TCP keep-alive flag ? Who and how does it know when to set the keep alive flag on TCP?
I'm wondering if TCP layer doesn't read Application (HTTP Headers) Keep-Alive property. How would it know to set the TCP keep alive flag? Does the browser read our request and request the operating system to send out with the TCP Keep alive true ?


No. 2. It doesn't. 3. TCP does not inspect payloads for possible HTTP Keep-alive headers. 4. It doesn't. 5. No. [The TCP keepalive feature is misnamed.]


Does this answer your question? HTTP Keep Alive and TCP keep alive, HTTP KeepAlive can be as a substitute for TCP KeepAlive?

@user207421 Thank you, I provided my answer - is it a correct understanding ?

@user207421: The TCP keepalive feature is not misnamed. It's original purpose was keeping idle sessions alive through stateful firewall.

@Joshua No. See RFC 1122. Its original purpose was for Telnet to detect dead connections via a 2-hour timeout, long before stateful firewalls were invented, and even in a local network.

No, no it is not. Http Keep alive keeps the connection open for X seconds to use again. TCP keepalive notices when connections break over X minutes. They can be used independently.
There's lots of reasons to use both; but the reasons are independent of each other.
TCP keepalive is secondary to application timeouts. If you can't use application timeouts or have to set too high a maximum, you can arrange for TCP keepalive to kick in and bail the request when the connection is broken  without waiting for the application timeout to finish.
If you call the same server over and over again, you want HTTP keepalive so you don't have to set up a new connection for every request. This pays several times over with TLS so you don't pay for new TLS connections every request.
TCP keepalive can detect broken pooled connections; so it would seem that this is a good thing to use with HTTP keepalive; however it really isn't. The default TCP keepalive interval is longer than the default idle connection pool linger time so it really doesn't help there.

Thank you, I think your response help me understand it a bit more. I replied my own answer hoping it is the correct understanding ?

Thank you for your response Joshua. If I understand correctly, this is what I'm understanding at the moment:
HTTP: keep-alive
An optimization to minimize new TCP connection per subsequent request, otherwise would require client to do three way handshake and TLS handshake on every request.

HTTP without keep-alive: Will initiate to close after each request/response.

HTTP keep-alive: Will have a timeout but if it is longer (usually shorter) than TCP’s default timeout - that TCP connection will be terminated by OS rather than web server.

Bound by TCP timeout is more likely to happen if you are using WebSockets (which is why websocket sends pingpong frames every 20 seconds).**



[pingpong frames] It creates a trickle of traffic so that the TCP connection isn’t idle and network infrastructure along the path keeps it open (“keepalive”).
Websocket Docs

TCP: keep-alive
A self-reinforcing mechanism to prevent the connection from getting destroyed by the internal timeout (ex. delta time between packet to packet longer than 60 seconds will close connection).

Most operating systems disable this keep-alive feature. so idle-connection close relies on timeout around 60 seconds (default).
Enabling Keep Alive will keep connections open for a long time. For example keeping the connection reserved/open for 2 hours+ (adjustable)


"TCP Keepalives are sent every 45 or 60 seconds on an idle TCP connection, and the connection is dropped after 3 sequential ACKs are missed." - Wiki


"To test idle TCP connections and ensure they are still active. By default, 'keepalive' is set to 7200000ms (2 hours)." Esri

Base on whats above, I guess it's a combination of regular pulses and then finally a renewal on the keep-alive over a longer period like like 2 hours?

TCP keep alive is not "to prevent the connection from getting destroyed by the internal timeout" on client or server. It is about a) detecting loss of connectivity even if no application data are transmitted and b) keeping the state active in intermediate stateful devices (NAT, firewall) without transmitting application data so that they don't break an idle connection. And HTTP keep-alive is only about keeping the TCP connection open for the next HTTP request instead of closing it. This means it has nothing to do with Websockets since there is no such thing as a "next request" in Websockets.

Thanks, then TCP keep alive is like a health check and time extension. Regarding HTTP and websocket I agree ! I literally said "to minimize [prevent] new TCP connection per subsequent request" Sorry for the confusion - for Websockets, I just want to make the point how application layer is bounded by TCP's own timeout. Thats why i quote their heartbeat mechanism. They have their reason to not just use TCP-keepalive there "TCP keepalive is disabled by default on most operating systems. When enabled, the default interval is two hours or more, which is far too much." - websockets doc @SteffenUllri

Websockets are a mechanism to have TCP like features (i.e. arbitrary bidirectional communication) in a restrictive environment where plain TCP with arbitrary ports with the outside world is not allowed (corporate networks, several hotels, ...). This is solved by upgrading from HTTP to Websockets. There is not control about the behavior of the underlying TCP stack in this case, specifically if application proxies are also involved (which terminate the TCP connection and create a new one). So websockets can't use TCP keep alive end to end.
